# SSH remote command execution in script

Tags: ssh

In my script I do something like this:

```
command="some/path/script.sh arg1 arg2; some/path/script2.sh arg1 arg2;"
ssh_command="ssh root@$ip '$command'"

echo $ssh_command
exec $ssh_command
```

The echo gives output like this:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 'some/path/script.sh arg1 arg2; some/path/script2.sh arg1 arg2;'
```

After the "exec" thing I get the output:

```
bash: some/path/script.sh arg1 arg2; some/path/script2.sh arg1 arg2;: No such file or directory
```

However, when copy the command from echo output and run it directly from the terminal it works like charm. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

[Nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) may be useful to you.

Try integrating something like this from the link below.

> ssh -n -f user@host "**sh -c** 'cd /whereever; nohup ./whatever > /dev/null 2>&1 &'"

https://stackoverflow.com/q/29142/1666510

Comment: nohup is a useful tool, but the part of your command that actually solves the problem is the "sh -c", not nohup.

Answer (score 0):

`exec` replaces the shell with a program, invoking it with the arguments supplied. The shell sees 2 tokens: "exec", and "some/path/script.sh arg1 arg2; some/path/script2.sh arg1 arg2;". The second argument is interpreted as a path to a program to execute, including all the spaces and semicolons. Only a shell knows to split arguments on whitespace and to separate commands at a semicolon. Therefore, you should replace the `exec` with a call to a shell, like `sh -c "$ssh_command"`.

Comment: Or, do what you probably really meant to: `eval "$ssh_command"`.  The quotes might not be necessary.  If you want this to end the script, use `eval exec $ssh_command`.